# custom base 64 not using .net FromBase64String

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to encrypt decrypt a string. using base 64 with custom characters well one custom character chr(255) (-). I would like to use the built in ,net  FromBase64String  but it errors with invalid characters. If i use the below code (see link) and change the character / to - it works. Any ideas to make this work using .nets built in functions.

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5248.

Thanks all

Comment: Technically, if you're using "base 64 with custom characters", you're not using base64. Nonetheless, why not just do a string replace first?

Comment: Also, base-64 conversion **is not encryption**; if you think that it is: ***stop now; bad things; bad things***

Comment: @MarcGravell i know its not encryption but for obfuscation. Its already in use but i want to tidy up the old asp based code. thank you

Comment: @AdrianWragg, 

i tried a replace first but it did not work. Basically if the code from the link can be tidied up to run faster i could use that, just not sure where to start with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done with a function that does a `string.Replace`, like this:

```
public string CustomToBase64String(byte[] data)
{
    var s = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    return s.Replace('/', (char)255);
}

public byte[] CustomFromBase64String(string s)
{
    var changed = s.Replace((char)255, '/');
    return Convert.FromBase64String(s);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry i have not replied sooner. I had already tried this approach but the char 255 was not in the string as already encryped. Thanks for your help though. I have used it the same as in the link i attached in the post.